# The solution to a summation $4^n/(4^n+2 )$

Tags: summation

I found this problem on summations, and I'm not really sure how to solve it. Could someone give a hint as to how to do so?
Find the value of

$$\sum_{i=1}^{1000}f\left(\frac{i}{1000}\right),\qquad f(x) = \frac{4^x}{4^x+2}$$ It came on an exam where we couldn't use calculators, and it apparently is an integer answer, though Wolfram Alpha disagrees...(Even if it isn't, I would still like to know how to do it)

Comment: what is this $$\sum_{i=1}^{1000}=$$?

Comment: Umm... I meant to say the summation of the thing? For i=1 to 1000?

Comment: But what is the _thing_?

Comment: What is the _summand_? Do you have definition of _f(n)_?

Comment: Use If $f(n)=\dfrac{4^n}{4^n+2}$

$$f(1-n)=\dfrac{4^{1-n}}{4^{1-n}+2}=\dfrac4{4+2\cdot4^n}=\dfrac2{2+4^n}=1-f(n)$$

Comment: I'm sorry about that, not really familiar with the formal notation. What i meant to say is, if f(n)=4^n/(4^n)+2, find the sum of the values of it as n ranges from 1/1000 to 1

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot, that helped. So, everything cancels out to give 500 then?

Comment: @AnishHebbar: It would if $i = 0$ were the lower limit.  As it is, I think you're missing a $1/3$ term.

Comment: Yeah, noticed that. My bad!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We have
$$ f(x)+f(1-x) = \frac{4^x}{4^x+2}+\frac{4^{1-x}}{4^{1-x}+2} = \frac{4^x}{4^x+2}+\frac{2}{4^x+2}=1 $$
hence
$$ \left[f\left(\frac{1}{1000}\right)+f\left(\frac{999}{1000}\right)\right]+\ldots+\left[f\left(\frac{499}{1000}\right)+f\left(\frac{501}{1000}\right)\right]=499 $$
and your sum is just $499+f(1)+f\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=\color{red}{500+\frac{1}{6}}$.

Comment: @JackDAurizio: Nice answer! (+1)

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{n=1}^{1000}\frac{4^n}{4^n+2} = \sum_{n=1}^{1000}\frac{2^{2n}}{2^{2n}+2}  =  \sum_{n=1}^{1000}\frac{2^{2n-1}}{2^{2n-1}+1}  = \frac23 + \frac89 + \frac{32}{33} + \frac{128}{129} + \cdots + \frac{2^{1999}}{{2^{1999}+1}} \approx 999.5149000482058.$$

Comment: But this answers a different question-- I summed over 1 to 1000 instead of 1/1000 to 1.  Should I just delete the post in a situation like this?

Comment: I wouldn't delete it, but I would add something in it to state that the question you answered was different (due to a lack of clarity in the question or a misunderstanding by you).